# Self-Signed Certificate for Public and Private IP (Tomcat 7)

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am configuring a server that has both a public and private IP. It doesn't have any associated domain names.

Using a self-signed certificate to access the URL below works properly:

```
    https://<PUBLIC IP>:8443
```

However, when I try to access that server using its private IP:

```
    wget https://<PRIVATE IP>:8443
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: cannot verify 's certificate, issued by '/C=?/ST=?/L=?/O=?/OU=?/CN=Unknown':
>     Self-signed certificate encountered.
>       ERROR: certificate common name 'Unknown' doesn't match requested host name ''.
>   To connect to  insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Is there a way to specify in the configuration that both public and private IPs should be accepted?

I also tried including multiple connectors in server.xml containing the address attribute but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can create certificate with two hosts(Public and Private IP) as explained here  :

http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm

**Configuring ssl requests with SubjectAltName with openssl**

With Multiple Domain Certificates you can secure a larger number of domains with only one certificate. Subject Alternative Names are a X509 Version 3 (RFC 2459) extension to allow an SSL certificate to specify multiple names that the certificate should match. SubjectAltName can contain email addresses, IP addresses, regular DNS host names, etc. This uses an SSL feature called SubjectAlternativeName (or SAN, for short).

**Generate the Certificate Request File**

For a generic SSL certificate request (CSR), openssl doesn't require much fiddling. Since we're going to add a SAN or two to our CSR, we'll need to add a few things to the openssl conf file. You need to tell openssl to create a CSR that includes x509 V3 extensions and you also need to tell openssl to include a list of subject alternative names in your CSR.

Create an openssl configuration file which enables subject alternative names (openssl.cnf):
In the [req] section. This is the section that tells openssl what to do with certificate requests (CSRs).
Within that section should be a line that begins with req_extensions. We'll want that to read as follows:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
```

This tells openssl to include the v3_req section in CSRs. 
Now we'll go own down to the v3_req section and make sure that it includes the following:

```
[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = US
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = MN
localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = Minneapolis
organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = Domain Control Validated
commonName = Internet Widgits Ltd
commonName_max  = 64

[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = kb.example.com
DNS.2 = helpdesk.example.org
DNS.3 = systems.example.net
IP.1 = 192.168.1.1
IP.2 = 192.168.69.14
```

**Generate a private key**
You'll need to make sure your server has a private key created:

```
openssl genrsa -out san_domain_com.key 2048
```

**Create the CSR file**

Then the CSR is generated using:

```
openssl req -new -out san_domain_com.csr -key san_domain_com.key -config openssl.cnf
```

You'll be prompted for information about your organization, and it'll ask if you want to include a passphrase (you don't). It'll then finish with nothing much in the way of feedback. But you can see that san_domain_com.csr has been created.

We can take a look at what the csr contains with the following command:

```
openssl req -text -noout -in san_domain_com.csr
```

You should see some output like below. Note the Subject Alternative Name section:

```
Certificate Request:
Data:
Version: 0 (0x0)
Subject: C=US, ST=Texas, L=Fort Worth, O=My Company, OU=My Department, CN=server.example
Subject Public Key Info: Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
Modulus (2048 bit): blahblahblah
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
Attributes:
Requested Extensions: X509v3
Basic Constraints: CA:FALSE
X509v3 Key Usage: Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:kb.example.com, DNS:helpdesk.example.com
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
blahblahblah
```

So now we've got a new CSR. But, of course, we have to sign it.

**Self-sign and create the certificate:**

```
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in san_domain_com.csr -signkey san_domain_com.key
 -out san_domain_com.crt-extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LarryShatzer ok I will add the essential parts . Thanks for letting me know .